# Can schools require that students use school-provided computers?

Tags: parental-rights

I am a parent of a four year old.  She will be starting Kindergarten in August 2023 and my school system provides Chromebooks to all students.  I do not want my kid to have their own computer when they are five.  Can the school system legally require my daughter to have a computer?

Comment: What is the jurisdiction and is this a private school or public? What is the school mandating that the student use the computer for? I don't think the child-abuse tag is applicable unless some very restrictive conditions are imposed.

Comment: I think you need to define "force" here.  It's quite possible that the school has developed a curriculum that is based on the use of a computer.  In that case a student who doesn't have one will likely NOT be able to complete any schoolwork.  Perhaps you should consider an alternative school, home schooling, or get yourself elected to the school board to make changes from the inside.

Comment: @doneal24 The only scenarios I can imagine that might warrant "child abuse" would be if the school literally coats the computer with superglue and sticks it to the child's skin.  I think that would qualify as abuse in most places.  I also cannot imagine that happening.

Comment: @jwh20 I'm also not sure that a parent has a "contract" with their public school district. And please do not suggest superglue to my supervisor even though it make touch-typing difficult. :)

Comment: @jwh20 at least one US state includes damaging a child's mental health or welfare in its child protection laws, so someone who believes that giving a computer to a 5-year-old is likely to be deleterious can reasonably add the tag.  I don't imagine that the argument would stand up in a court, though, because I imagine that there is no expert consensus in the question.

Comment: @phoog I always wince when I see a two year old attached to a phone or tablet when the parent is shopping. I can't believe that it is beneficial to the child but is always a delegation of parental responsibilities. Fortunately, I've always managed to keep my mouth shut.

Comment: Not sure why the child abuse tag is added to this question as user of a computer in school isn't child abuse.

Comment: What is your concern about your child having access to a computer? What steps has the school taken to prevent problems?

Comment: **I think you are being overconcerned.** The school can't force your child to use a computer for anything other than schoolwork. In terms of her "having their own computer" you are entitled to restrict their access outside school - for example taking control of the computer when the child leaves school and supervising her so that they do only what is required for school. Given that, there is no real problem with "having" a computer as opposed to "having access to" a computer.

Answer (score 4):

If the school is a private school, then definitely yes: the school can also mandate clothing and grooming standards, and so forth – attending private school is optional, and they can even require the parents to provide the computer. (Mandatory) public schools have less power, but they still have the right to require students to do things that the parents do not like. For example, a parent might not like the particular history curriculum, or the might not like the fact that the child has to study music, but that is a power granted to public school districts.

If the requirement were "unreasonable" in some sense, parental prerogative might win out over the school's rational of educational necessity. But it is no more unreasonable to require a student to learn how to use a computer that it is to require them to learn how to read a book. You might argue that reading is "more necessary" than developing computer skills, but the school district's curricular judgment is placed above that of a parent, so you would have to establish that giving a child access to a computer is objectively unreasonable.